# Unable to compile c++ code with Curl library, but Curl still works in the command line Windows 10

Tags: c++, libcurl, mingw-w64

I recently installed curl on my Windows 10 computer via vcpkg. When I run it from the command line, everything seems to work fine. However, when I try and run this sample code on VS Code, I get a compiler error:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"

void testCurl() {
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res; 

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); 

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

#ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
#endif

#ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
#endif

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

if (res != CURLE_OK)
   fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
   curl_easy_strerror(res));

   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
}

int main(){
   testCurl();
   return 0;
}
```

I am using powershell to compile. I've tried compiling with the following commands:

```
g++ CurlExample.cpp
g++ -lcurl CurlExample.cpp
g++ -lcurl/curl CurlExample.cpp
```

And I receive the following error:

```
CurlExample.cpp:1:10: fatal error: curl: No such file or directory
```

It seems as though VS Code recognizes the library, which it previously didn't before installing curl, so I am guessing I am missing a step with my compiler. Any suggestions?

Comment: your installed curl.exe has nothing to do with the libcurl headers your compiler is telling you you're missing. Can you look for `curl.h` and check whether it is in the include paths your g++ searches for by default? Generally, you would use a build system that finds your libraries and uses the right paths for your compiler automatically.

Comment: You are confusing `-l` and `-I` compiler options.